# Frames for formulas

Tags: latex

How can I make a colored frame with rounded corners around the numbered formula? And so that the frame is the size of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation,colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thank you very much! I know the tcolorbox package, I just didn't know about tcbhighmath.